# why does ssh loops with "SECURE CONNECTION REFUSED"?

Tags: security

why does ssh loops with "SECURE CONNECTION REFUSED"?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What are you trying to accomplish? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. What results did you get? 4. How did that differ from the results you were expecting? (please be more specific, these are not self-evident from the current state of your question)

Comment: We can only guess at what is wrong. Adding more information about what you are doing and have tried will help you get a better answer.

Comment: This is one weird question -- straight out from the SSH FAQ! http://stason.org/TULARC/security/ssh/5-12-Why-does-ssh-loop-with-Secure-connection-refused.html

Comment: @chx: you should post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is one weird question -- straight out from the [SSH FAQ](http://stason.org/TULARC/security/ssh/5-12-Why-does-ssh-loop-with-Secure-connection-refused.html)!